# Problem with permissions when saving a copy of a spreadsheet to a shared folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

This is the first time I have posted so please excuse any breaches of etiquette!

I have developed a spreadsheet for our business to use when cashing up tills with some basic scripts to add functionality. One of these allows the user to 'submit' the cashing up by saving a copy of the spreadsheet in a shared folder renamed with the date the user was working on. The script then clears the contents of the unprotected ranges ready to be used again. I am the owner of both the spreadsheet and the folder, but I have shared both to the users with 'editor' permissions.

My problem is when they come to run the script that submits the cashing up, it gives an exception that states

> You do not have permission to access the requested document".

When I run the script myself it works as planned.

Here is the script

```
//Function to set filename and copy to archive
function nameAndArchive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newfilename = ss.getSheetByName('Calculations').getRange(4, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1GVlutqUFOEWGmeqEdQU8v7J4DZh9fZ1J'); 

  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(newfilename, destFolder);
}
```

I can't figure out how I can change the permissions to get the script to function as intended. Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Scripts will run as the person that invoked them. What are the permissions of the Sheet and folders that you're trying to access in the script? If the folder is in your Drive you must share it with those who are running the script.

Comment: Hi, the permissions for the sheet and the folder are set to editor for all users, as far as I can see that is the highest access level possible short of owner?

Comment: It is indeed. What is the line that throws the error?

Comment: This is where I get the error:
DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(newfilename, destFolder);

Comment: Is it a folder that's shared with the others, or a shared Drive?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, having looked more closely I realised that the error is on a line that calls a different function where access had not been granted to a required sheet. I have shared that with the team and now it works as expected. Thanks for your help @RafaGuillermo!